# Ubuntu 14.04 mouse pointer does not move

Tags: unity, 14.04, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, after updating the Unity doesn't load. The sidebar and topbar disappear. On the main screen, there are only the background and the pointer. I've solved this problem by entering these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo shutdown -r now
```

After rebooting, the side bar does appear, however now the mouse pointer disappears. I make the pointer visible by entering this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

The mouse pointer now appears but it does not move (it freezes). Can someone guide me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well after running those commands. I pulled up a terminal, issued a `sudo reboot`, and all was well after that.